# Need work around for downloading xlsx from website

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

i am trying to obtain data provided in an xslx spreadsheet for download from a url link via python. my fist approach was to read it into a dataframe and save it down to a file that can be manipulated via another script.

i have realized that xlsx is no longer supported by xlrd due to security concerns. my current thought of a workaround is to download to a seperate file, convert to xls and vthen do my initial process/manipulations. i am new to python and wondering if this is the best way to accomplish. i see a potential problem in this method, as the security concern is still present. this particular document probably is downloaded by many institutions daily, so incentive for hacking source doc and deploying bug is high. am i overthinking?

what method would you use to call xlsx into pandas from a static url...additionally, this is my next problem - downloading a document from a dynamic URL and any tips on where to look would be helpful.

my original source code is below, the problem i am trying to accomplish is maintaining a database of all s&p500 constituents and their current weightings.

thank you.

```
# packages
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ssga.com/us/en/institutional/etfs/library-content/products/fund-data/etfs/us/holdings-daily-us-en-spy.xlsx'

# Load the first sheet of the Excel file into a data frame
df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name=0, header=1)

# View the first ten rows
df.head(10)

#is it worth it to download file to a repisotory, convert to xls, then read in?
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html change the engine to openpyxl. You may have to install it first

Answer (score 0):

You can always make the request with requests and then read the xlsx into a pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

from io import BytesIO

url = ("https://www.ssga.com/us/en/institutional/etfs/library-content/"
       "products/fund-data/etfs/us/holdings-daily-us-en-spy.xlsx")

r = requests.get(url)
bts = BytesIO(r.content)
df = pd.read_excel(bts)
```

I'm not sure about the security concerns but this would be equivalent to just making the same request in a browser. As for the dynamic url, if you can figure out which parts of the url are changing you can just modify it as follows

```
stock = 'spy'
url = ("https://www.ssga.com/us/en/institutional/etfs/library-content/"
       f"products/fund-data/etfs/us/holdings-daily-us-en-{stock}.xlsx")
```